# Failed to construct transformer: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported in React native

Tags: node.js, react-native, gradle, metro-bundler

I am trying to run a react native app, the app build successfully, but it fails to launch stating that metro was unable to connect, throwing error that development server returned 500 error, here are the Screenshots: -

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjysi.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt1lJ.jpg)

I am using NodeJS v16.13.2, also tried using node v14, but same issue

here is the issue

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at stableHash (/Users/akashlakhani/Desktop/ReactNative/cintas-mobile/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)
    at JsTransformer.getCacheKey (/Users/akashlakhani/Desktop/ReactNative/cintas-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/JSTransformer/worker.js:478:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (/Users/akashlakhani/Desktop/ReactNative/cintas-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer/getTransformCacheKey.js:39:29)
    at new Transformer (/Users/akashlakhani/Desktop/ReactNative/cintas-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:147:28)
    at /Users/akashlakhani/Desktop/ReactNative/cintas-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:54:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
[Tue Sep 12 2023 16:09:07.906]  BUNDLE  ./index.js 

error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
    at /Users/akashlakhani/Desktop/ReactNative/cintas-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:91:34
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/akashlakhani/Desktop/ReactNative/cintas-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:14:24)
    at _next (/Users/akashlakhani/Desktop/ReactNative/cintas-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:34:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Here is the package.json file for your reference: -

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "bundle": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/",
    "build:android:prod": "cd android && SET ENVFILE=.env.production && gradlew assembleRelease",
    "build:android:dev": "cd android && SET ENVFILE=.env.production && gradlew assembleDebug",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "query-string": "^6.14.1",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-config": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.2.41",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.6.2",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-version-info": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.8.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.2.3",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.7.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.13",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.3.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-devtools": "^4.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Please help us in solving this issue, as i have tried multiple ways to solve it as suggested in other stackoverflow solutions, as well as react native github issues solutions. but none of them worked.

An early reply is appreaciated

Thankyou in advance folks

Answer (score 3):

This happens due to conflicts in Node versions. I was able to resolve the issue by adding NODE_OPTIONS env below. You can add this env variables to your profile, so when you restart the SO they will be there. (eg: ~/.zshrc for mac. or /etc/profile for linux )

Linux / macOS

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Windows

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Answer (score 0):

The "digital envelope routines" error could be due to Node.js version compatibility. Try using Node.js v14 Again

The "transformFile" error may relate to Metro bundler configuration. Double-check your Metro setup and ensure your project dependencies match React Native 0.62.2. Maybe even update the metro-react-native-babel-preset to newest version.

Comment: node.js 14 should be better for you
try npm cache clean -f in terminal
try: rm -rf node modules
rm -f package-lock.json
npm install
cd android && ./gradlew clean
cd .. && react-native run-android
check the typeerror to see if it leads to the crash